# How to speed up webpack rebuild of npm library of components and classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm coding npm-package which exports React UI-components and typescript classes. I check how it works by building the whole package and linking it with yarn to React project.

And I want to speed up its rebuild. But I'm confused with all code-splitting, hot module replacement things. I tried to add second entry point and to create shared bundle between entrypoints but the size of each entrypoint stayed as big as if it was doubled size of initial entrypoint. And as I understand hot module replacement doesn't work without code splitting.

So I need hints about what should I do with webpack configuration to optimize rebuild. Now build lasts for nearly 30 seconds.

**Current package-structure**

```
/src
  /components 
  /modules
  index.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
export {Component1, Component2} from './components';
export {AbstractClass1, AbstractClass2} from './modules';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const EsmWebpackPlugin = require('@purtuga/esm-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    configFile: 'tsconfig.json'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'LIB',
        libraryTarget: 'var'
    },
    plugins: [new EsmWebpackPlugin({moduleExternals: true})],
    externals: ['react', 'react-dom']
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noEmit": false,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "**/__tests__/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @guerric-p, can you watch, please?

Comment: maybe @matthiku can help?

Comment: or @dimitar-dimitrov can give a hint?

Comment: @christos-lytras?